# How to set header in request for HAProxy based on script output?

Tags: authentication, microservices, load-balancing, haproxy

I have haproxy which runs fine, but we have backend, which validate token against our identity service.

I want to move that logic to HAProxy, where we can run some python or sh script, and get the user name and its ldap groups.

Then we don't have to check for token in each services. We just have to check it the user request has that username and ldapgroup headers or not. If its not, backend will not server the request.

I was checking on google, found some leads like there is [`add-header` and `set-header`](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/latest/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/) to update the headers info in request or response.

I also found the [`external_check`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-external-check%20command) which will execute script and take decision.

What I am looking for is combination of `add-header`/`set-header` and `external-check`? Where it will execute the script and set the headers.

Comment: The token contains the username and LDAP groups? Is this OpenID Connect or OAuth? Or a custom type of token? I ask because I am working on updating the HAProxy OAuth Lua library so that it extracts claims from a token, which could then be examined in HAProxy using ACLs.

Comment: @NickRamirez, token is just string, but when we validate with our identity service, in response it will return valid LDAP groups. We want to pass that LDAP Groups to other API as header. 

If the token is not valid, identity return you error code, we will return that error code back.